# IOS device time string received with bad formats

Tags: ios, datetime, nsdate

In my IOS app i am sending the device time of the user to my server for analysis.
this is the code that makes the device time string that gets sent:

```
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[dateFormatter setCalendar:gregorianCalendar];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate* currentTime = [NSDate date];
NSString* deviceTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];

[gregorianCalendar release];
[dateFormatter release];
```

i thought that this should cover all different calendars and setting that the IOS device may have and consistently make a string that could formatted into datetime. but this is not the case. some times the device may send something strange for example:

```
২০১৪-০৫-১৯ ০১:৫১:২৪
```

i tried to change the settings of my test device to different configurations to reproduce this but i was not able to. did anybody else encounter this problem?

Comment: Where is the code that actually send it to the server?  And this issue is most likely on the server end.

Comment: Try: `[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];` to be independent of the region settings on the device.

Comment: Why Zaph's code will work: The app formats the time by default according to the settings of the user. If the user set his device to a language that displays digits differently, that's what you will get. en_US_POSIX is a format that is guaranteed to stay unchanged forever, even if in the future for example US or UK date formats were going to change. So this code will work forever (well, until the end of the year 9999).

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks for the full background.

Answer (score 1):

To be independent of the region settings on the device use the local `en_US_POSIX`:

```
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

This also handles the 12 hour vs 24 hour problem.